# Sends from epoch, for 1 year ago on MacOS / BSD?

Tags: macos, date, epoch, bsd

I'm trying to calculate the number of seconds since the Epoch, using date on MacOS BSD.

I can get a one year ago date string:

```
$ date -v -1y

Tue Apr 21 10:44:47 EST 2020
```

...but I can't figure out how to convert it into seconds since Epoch.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `+%s`. See [`man strftime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strftime.3.html).

Comment: Awesome, if you make that an answer I will happily accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `+%s` to tell it to print the datetime as seconds since the epoch:

```
date -v -1y +%s
```

The `+` is a `date` option to set the output format, and `%s` is [strftime](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strftime.3.html) format for "seconds since epoch".

Portability note: while the `+%s` part is pretty standard and portable (though the `%s` format is not actually required by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html#tag_20_30)), the `-v -1y` part is wildly nonportable. With GNU date (e.g. on most Linuxes), you'd use something like `--date='1 year ago'` instead. On NetBSD, `-d '1 year ago'` works. Check your local `man` page to see what your system supports.